# This spotlight effect is not working in Safari 7.1+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Why does this CodePen not work in Safari? Of all the spotlight tutorials, I ran with this one because it did what I wanted. It works in Chrome/Firefox, but doesn't work at all (not even partially) in Safari 7.1+. Could somebody shed some light?

http://codepen.io/cchambers/pen/Dyldj

```js
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e){  
  $(".spotlight").css("left",e.clientX-100).css("top", e.clientY-100);
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/KHucaTQ.jpg);
    background-size:100% auto;
    overflow:hidden;
} 
.spotlight{
    cursor:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px; 
    left:200px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:transparent;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,.85);
}

.ha{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spotlight ha"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using? It works fine in Safari 5.1+.

Comment: Looks fine in version 6.1.6 but not in version  7.1.7

Comment: What specificlally is not working? The entire thing? Is there a spotlight but it is not a circle? Is the effect reversed? etc.

Comment: No effect at all. The image does not darken and i do not see the spotlight. My friend has safari version 7.1.3 and it does not work on his either.

Comment: I can confirm that it is not working on Safari 8.0.6 either.

Comment: It is looking like a bug in Safari that was introduced in version 7.1+, but I don't know how to file those, since Safari is closed-source.

Comment: I changed 2000px to 1500px and it works. very strange and i don't really understand what the difference is.

Comment: did you add commas or anything else? Just the change from 2000 to 1500? That's odd! Don't forget to accept your own answer so others know what the solution was :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that to fix the issue at hand, I had to change the "spread" in the box-shadow to be `1900px` instead of `2000px`. Not in any way shape or form sure why, but that at least fixed it on my version of Safari. Will check version 8 and some others and hope that fixes it.

Just wanted to add the snippit of code in case this could halp anybody

```
.spotlight{
  cursor:none;
  position:absolute;

  top:24%;
  left:7%;

  height:20%;
  width:17%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:transparent;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1900px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
  z-index: 2;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your css to this:

```
.spotlight{
  cursor:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px; left:200px;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:transparent;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,.85);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,.85);
}
```

The added `-webkit-` should do the trick.

Alternatively, update your Safari - you may be running an outdated version.

---

Read up on `box-shadow` and it's browser compatibility: [box-shadow - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: `box-shadow` has been supported unprefixed since Safari 5.1, which came out in 2012.

Comment: Hence the alternate solution.

Comment: I'm running the latest version of safari but that codepen still does not work. I am able to view other examples of box shadowing in my version of safari there is just somethign wrong with that code that i can't figure out.

Comment: Crazy enough i checked my laptop its running version 6.1.6 and it works fine, but my desktop has version 7.1.7 and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The key being i forgot to add -webkit-border-radius. Silly mistake

```
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: Are you sure? `border-radius` has been supported unprefixed in Safari since version 5.

Comment: YOu are correct, i got my browsers confused. I do not understand why this isn't working.

Comment: What remains, I think is to start isolating parts of the code in new demos and try to isolate the root cause. We won't be able to solve the problem until we know which part of the code, exactly, isn't working in Safari 7.1+. I would start by checking in the Developer Window of Safari to see if any of the CSS properties are being ignored as invalid (they would have a yellow ! caution sign next to them and be stricken through).